# Ghost Inspector tests are failing on running

Tags: ghost-inspector

I record test using Ghost Inspector on a website. But when I run the test in Ghost Inspector, one of the buttons is always greyed (only in the test run), and the test fails. Not sure why this is happening. When I record the button is not greyed.

This is the console output in Ghost Inspector:

> 1788:23079 Uncaught Error: Error in attempt to create DIL instance
>   with DIL.c…pendency for DIL v8.0+: Invalid Visitor instance.

The same test if recorder and playback using Selenium IDE runs fine

I also tried exporting the failing test from Ghost Inspector as Selenium IDE (new) and opened in Selenium IDE, and test ran successfully

Comment: Ghost Inspector support here - turns out there were some steps missing in the test that would trigger the form validation to allow submission. Be sure to reach out to support again if you run into any other issues!

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the code/test its a bit hard to tell but I'll take a shot in the dark

1) could be ghost inspector test settings. I would go into settings at the top right corner when you are inside your test and look at browser settings. Make sure you're using the browser you want as well as the correct screen size.

2) Could be a timing issue. You might need to add an assertion to let the button load before trying to click that button.

If these don't help let us know a bit more about the test steps as well as the button you are targeting. what is its function and what are the circumstances when its supposed to be disabled.